# dismiss viewcontroller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

this is the code for my facebook login, when i finish the login the FaceBookLogIn.xib don't dismiss properly,

when i exit the app and relaunch it work fine and my main view appear.

how can i dismiss the viewcontroller as soon as the user singin ?

***update***

i move all the code from app AppDelegate to my main view controller

and when i sing in i get in the nslog

"2013-12-07 13:02:49.650 barbar[2275:70b] User session found"

bat still the view don't dismiss

if i exit and return to the app it show the tabbarviewcontroler and i get my nslog -

2013-12-07 13:06:42.162 barbar[2303:70b] User Logged Innnnn

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    if (FBSession.activeSession.state
        == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

        NSLog(@"User Logged Innnnn");
        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
    //create and present the login view controller
    else {
        NSLog(@"the user not login");
        FacebookConect * showfacebookconnectview = [[FacebookConect alloc]initWithNibName:@"FacebookConect" bundle:Nil];
        [self presentViewController:showfacebookconnectview animated:YES completion:Nil];


    }
    animated = YES;
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    /*
     we pass this permissions array into our request
     I only request email, but there are many more options
     */
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            nil];

    return [FBSession
            openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
            allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                FBSessionState state,
                                NSError *error) {
                [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                    state:state
                                    error:error];

            }];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}



@end
```

Comment: Do you want to have it as navigation controller or changing views ?

Comment: i wont to chang views.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the AppDelegate to show login screens directly. It looks as though you are using Storyboards/Xib's to show your interface. For this reason, I'd allow the default operation to happen (because you're preventing it by setting the `rootViewController` property manually). Then, in your main view controller, have the check for Facebook that would bring up the dialog (`presentViewController:animated:completion:`) and can then be dismissed as above and your original main view controller will be shown.

Comment: i see , bat i have tabbarviewcontroller and i wont a view that don't connected to the main tabbarviewcontroller and then dismiss it , so can i do it in any other way ?

Comment: It shouldn't affect the tab bar view controller. When you use `presentViewController`, it will pop over the top of the tab bar view controller (as long as you target it)

Comment: ok i did this and there is an error  "Warning: Attempt to present <facebookconect: 0x9c48710> on <UITabBarController: 0x9e679a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
"

Comment: the code - [self presentViewController:showfacebookconnectview animated:YES completion:Nil];

Comment: i put the if statement in viewDidLoad

Comment: I think you have to put it in `viewDidAppear:` or `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: How are you dismissing it?

Comment: in the    "- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error"                             you can se the code above, if (FBSessionStateOpen) i set the comand [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];